# how to get sum of each input printed?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am new to C and need some help with this basic program. I want the program to print out the sum directly after the input. I tried to put `printf("..%d", sum);` inside the for brackets and got but program shuts after the first input. It works if I have a `scanf("%d", &value);` before the *For* and inside the for brackets but there for I don't get the format I want.
I want the values to be printed vertical, left side should be inputs and right side should be output as u can see in the image.

[image: Sample Input/Output]

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int  sum = 0, c, value;
    scanf("%d", &value);

    for (c = 1; c <= value; c++)
    {
        sum = sum + c;
        printf("..%d", sum);
        scanf("%d", &value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  When you say that you don't get the format you want, could you explain what format you are getting?

Comment: What is the second `scanf` inside the `for` loop for?  Also, you need a newline character in your `printf`.  I.e., `printf("..%d\n", sum);`.

Comment: The format I get now is like this 
1
12
33
6...
So I get the output first and beside that I have to write the new value. But What I want is to get output at the right side not on the left.

Comment: About the second scanf, Thats the problem. When I delete one of them the program doesn't work. Quite strange for me like I can't figure it out why and I think that creates problem with formating.

Comment: [edit] the question to update with requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are a bit confused about which values you are actually summing (or I am...) From your problem descriptions (and from how you have initialized your `for` loop), it appears you are to input the ending value and then are to sum from `1` to that value?

If that is the case, there is no need for additional input within the `for` loop, your loop variable provides all values you are supposed to add to your sum.

Additionally, you cannot use any user-input function correctly unless you ***validate the return*** to determine whether input succeeded or failed.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int  sum = 0, c, value;
    
    fputs ("sum from 1 to: ", stdout);                      /* prompt for input */
    
    if (scanf ("%d", &value) != 1 || value < 1) {           /* VALIDATE EVERY INPUT !!! */
        fputs ("  error: invalid integer input or negative value.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    putchar ('\n');                             /* add newline before output */
    
    /* you are looping over the values of c -- no input is necessary */
    for (c = 1; c <= value; c++)
    {
        sum = sum + c;                          /* sum */
        printf ("%2d\t\t\t%d\n", c, sum);       /* output value added and sum */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/suminput
sum from 1 to: 5

 1                      1
 2                      3
 3                      6
 4                      10
 5                      15
```

Or for 1-10:

```
$ ./bin/suminput
sum from 1 to: 10

 1                      1
 2                      3
 3                      6
 4                      10
 5                      15
 6                      21
 7                      28
 8                      36
 9                      45
10                      55
```

Or if invalid input is provided:

```
$ ./bin/suminput
sum from 1 to: twenty
  error: invalid integer input or negative value.
```

Or a negative value:

```
$ ./bin/suminput
sum from 1 to: -10
  error: invalid integer input or negative value.
```

No harm done.

---

**Taking Input For The Sum**

The other way I read your sample input and output (characterized by the `0` ending the loop), is that your task is simply to read inputs and sum them until the user enters 0 (or an invalid integer) displaying the sum after each input. That is quite a bit easier -- but the requirement to validate each input remains the same, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int  sum = 0, value;
    
    while (scanf ("%d", &value) == 1 && value != 0) {    /* input value */
        sum += value;                                    /* sum */
        printf ("%20d\n", sum);                          /* output sum */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/suminput2
1
                   1
2
                   3
3
                   6
4
                  10
5
                  15
0
```

Or any random values until `0` is entered:

```
$ ./bin/suminput2
1
                   1
-2
                  -1
3
                   2
-4
                  -2
5
                   3
-6
                  -3
0
```

(note: there are ways to place the input and output on the same line but that differs between compilers and operating systems. Windows could use the non-standard `getch()`, while on Linux you would need to do the same thing by changing input to non-cannonical mode with `tcsetattr()`. Another way would simply be to save the inputs until the user enters `0` and then to loop over all values input summing and displaying the values (though that would eliminate the `0` at the end of input show in your example input))

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions (and also whether I interpreted your question correctly). If you do need to enter each value to sum, let me know and I am happy to help further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
It seems like I can't explain my question and maybe its because I can't use coding terms. But i try it once again here. The code I submitted above is my code and it actually works as I want except the output format and I don't know how to get ride of one of scanfs that i have cuz I dnt think I should have two scanfs. I want both the input and the output at the same line where input is at the left and output is at the write and it continues vertical by each number the user writes. i can see it in your first example.

Comment: And while its a very basic c program so I dnt need to write it the way u wrote cuz ur code it quite complicated for me right now cuz I have just started with C.

Comment: That's where I was confused. If you read the value 1st and then loop, you  don't need a `scanf()` inside the loop. If you simply initialize `sum = 0;` before entering the loop, then just control your loop with the return from `scanf()` as I did in the second example. It all depends on what you need to accomplish. Without an input in the loop summing from `1` to the number -- you are simply producing a factorial. Controlling the while loop with your input, you are simply summing whatever values the user enters and then exiting the loop when the user enters `0` (makes sense as `sum + 0 == sum`

Comment: The second example matches your problem inputs of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0` and outputs `1, 3, 6, 10, 15` -- exactly.

Comment: `while (scanf ("%d", &value) && value != 0) {` in an infinite loop on end-of-file.  Suggest `while (scanf ("%d", &value) == 1 && value != 0) {`

Comment: Uugh there is supposed to be an `== 1` in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, That was what exactly I wanted. I thought of that once and tried it with for-loop but didn't work. Thanks again for ur time and help.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. I can't even blame that one on a copy/paste error... that's why you want to exercise your code thoroughly to pick up on those ... brain-fart moments `:)`